# Sqoop fails to import any rows

Tags: sql, hadoop, sqoop

I'm trying to import a dummy table (cities) into HDFS with the following command:

```
$ sqoop import --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.0.2.15:1521/XE --username system --password root --table cities --columns country,city --split-by id --target-dir /sqoop/output1
```

but no rows get imported.

The SQL statement that gets generated by Sqoop is

```
SELECT t.* FROM cities t WHERE 1=0
```

which is odd because 1 will never be equal to zero.

I'm running:

```
Hadoop 2.4.1
Sqoop 1.4.5
```

Comment: hduser@debian:~$  sqoop import --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.0.2.15:1521/XE --username system --password root --table cities --columns country,city --split-by id --target-dir /sqoop/output3

Comment: 14/09/30 14:22:46 INFO sqoop.Sqoop: Running Sqoop version: 1.4.5
14/09/30 14:22:47 INFO oracle.OraOopManagerFactory: Data Connector for Oracle and Hadoop is disabled.
14/09/30 14:22:47 INFO manager.SqlManager: Using default fetchSize of 1000
14/09/30 14:22:47 INFO tool.CodeGenTool: Beginning code generation
14/09/30 14:22:56 INFO manager.OracleManager: Time zone has been set to GMT
14/09/30 14:22:56 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: SELECT t.* FROM cities t WHERE 1=0

Comment: I noticed it says:  Creating input split with lower bound 'id IS NULL' and upper bound 'id IS NULL'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statement with "where 1=0" is generated just to get the list of columns. The actual select is done in the MR job later on.

The problem was that the "cities" table didn't belong to SYSTEM user.

Answer (score 0):

Josef try to delete split-by and set reducer (-m parameter) to 1. If it is going to be ok it means that your splitter is bad. I also had problem with connection string in format `jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.0.2.15:1521/XE`  (think it should be `jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.0.2.15:1521:XE` or jdbc:oracle:thin:@//10.0.2.15:1521/XE anyway - read this [JDBC](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/JDBC)). But for me only this format is working:

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@(description=(address=(protocol=tcp)(host=10.0.2.15)(port=1521))(connect_data=(service_name=XXXXXX)))
```